# ConcurrentModificationException in single Threaded unmodifiableList

Tags: java, collections

I have a single threaded application that iterates over a huge tree structure where children are stored in a list. The iterators always operate on an unmodifiable list:

```
public List<HierarchyNode> getChildren() {  
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);  
}
```

Still I get an ConcurrentModificationException at some point, which I thought impossible in an unmodifiable List? The iteration is done using a visitor... any ideas how this is possible?

EDIT: The only one who can modify this list is the Constructor of the class holding the list:

```
private final List<HierarchyNode> children;
```

Maybe this is related to the fact that the memory usage of thetree is fairly large (>4GB)?

Trace:

```
Testcase: testParserSingleFile(General.NetlistBuilder): Caused an ERROR
null
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1067)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitArchitectureNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:20)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitArchitectureNode(NetlistBuilder.java:40)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ArchitectureNode.accept(ArchitectureNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitEntityNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:33)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitEntityNode(NetlistBuilder.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.EntityNode.accept(EntityNode.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitComponentNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:27)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ComponentNode.accept(ComponentNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitInstanceNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:45)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitInstanceNode(NetlistBuilder.java:85)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.InstanceNode.accept(InstanceNode.java:89)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitArchitectureNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:21)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitArchitectureNode(NetlistBuilder.java:40)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ArchitectureNode.accept(ArchitectureNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitEntityNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:33)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitEntityNode(NetlistBuilder.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.EntityNode.accept(EntityNode.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitComponentNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:27)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ComponentNode.accept(ComponentNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitInstanceNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:45)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitInstanceNode(NetlistBuilder.java:85)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.InstanceNode.accept(InstanceNode.java:89)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitArchitectureNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:21)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitArchitectureNode(NetlistBuilder.java:40)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ArchitectureNode.accept(ArchitectureNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitEntityNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:33)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitEntityNode(NetlistBuilder.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.EntityNode.accept(EntityNode.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitComponentNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:27)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ComponentNode.accept(ComponentNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitInstanceNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:45)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitInstanceNode(NetlistBuilder.java:85)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.InstanceNode.accept(InstanceNode.java:89)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitGenerateNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:39)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitGenerateNode(NetlistBuilder.java:79)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.GenerateNode.accept(GenerateNode.java:27)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitArchitectureNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:21)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitArchitectureNode(NetlistBuilder.java:40)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.ArchitectureNode.accept(ArchitectureNode.java:25)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visitEntityNode(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:33)
    at com.bevm.semantics.netlist.NetlistBuilder.visitEntityNode(NetlistBuilder.java:33)
    at com.bevm.hierarchy.EntityNode.accept(EntityNode.java:33)
    at com.beckhoff.vmagic.hierarchy.HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.visit(HierarchyNodeVisitorImplementation.java:15)
    at General.NetlistBuilder.testParserSingleFile(NetlistBuilder.java:125)
```

Comment: I have faced the same issue earlier.

Comment: Can you show your iteration code?

Comment: Please write your complete stack trace.

Comment: This is generally caused by modifying a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: I know, and I have worked through the other questions asked here; but it is unmodifiable!!

Comment: The HierarchyNodes are changing/destroying/new during your iteration? And which type of List is children?

Comment: The size shouldn't be the problem. What happens, when children is accessed directly?

Comment: what do you mean by `iterated by a visitor`?

Comment: During the traversing no sorting or "lazy init" is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, most of you were right, ans the simple answer is that the list is not really unmodifiable... all objects of the same class do not use the getChildren() method and instead directly access the private member. So I'll have to continue my search in the code... your comments will help

Answer (score 10):

So `Collection.unmodifiableList` is not REALLY thread-safe. This is because it create an unmodifiable view of the underlying `List`. However if the underlying `List` is modified while the view is being iterated you will get the CME. Remember that a CME does not need to be caused by a seperate thread. If I do the following I will get a CME:

```
 for (String e : myList){
     myList.remove(5); // throws CME
 }
```

The better choice is Guava's [ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) which creates an immutable copy of the passed list.

For clarification due to comments, replace the posted code with:

```
 public List<HierarchyNode> getChildren() {  
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(children);  
    }
```

The `List` returned from this method is guarenteed to NEVER throw a CME.

Update:

If you are still trying to figure out why it is happining in your code, consider the following:

1. Can the list of `children` EVER be modified (I am referring to the modifiable `List` that is passed to `unmodifiableList`)?
2. Do any of the classes that call `getChildren` ever cause that class which holds the modifiable list to be invoked in a way that might update the list?
3. Or do any of the classes get an instance of an `Iterator` that is used more than once?

[ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)

Comment: Please elaborate your answer with example so that it can be understandable.

Comment: Thread safety seems fairly unrelated here: *"I have a single threaded application"*.

Comment: +1 Another solution is to copy it. `return new ArrayList<HierarchyNode>(children); `

Comment: well, thats a solution, but it doesn't solve the problem ;-). Again, this is single threaded AND it is unmodifiable...

Comment: @BennyBarns Again, as my post states, you can get a CME in a single thread and `unmodifiable` does not guarentee no CMEs because it creates a view. As my updated post states, using `ImmutableList` is guarenteed to NEVER throw a CME. Without seeing a LOT more of your code we cannot try to debug why you are getting the CME. However, `ImmutableList` WILL prevent it.

Comment: I have edited my post: the only one who could possibly modify the list is the constructor who is long since gone at the time in question...

Comment: The exception you get shows that something _must_ have modified the list.  There is no other explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> only one who can possibly modify this list is the Constructor of the class holding it

In this case you don't need to modify it at all. I suggest you make it always immutable and you won't get this issue.

In your constructor you can do

```
List<HierarchyNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
// create/modify collection.

this.children = Collections.immutableList(children);
```

This simplifies your method

```
public List<HierarchyNode> getChildren() {  
    return children;  
}
```

If you make these changes, I suspect you will find where the collection is being modified.

---

The problem is that `Collections.unmodifiableList()` prevents modification using the reference returned by this method.  It doesn't prevent modification to the collection you are wrapping.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("hello");
words.add("world");
List<String> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableList(words);
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(words);

System.out.println("Before modification");
System.out.println("words: " + words);
System.out.println("unmodifiable: " + unmodifiable);
System.out.println("copy: " + copy);

words.remove("hello");
words.add("hi");

System.out.println("\nAfter modification");
System.out.println("words: " + words);
System.out.println("unmodifiable: " + unmodifiable);
System.out.println("copy: " + copy);
```

prints

```
Before modification
words: [hello, world]
unmodifiable: [hello, world]
copy: [hello, world]

After modification
words: [world, hi]
unmodifiable: [world, hi]
copy: [hello, world]
```

The solution without adding a new library, is to copy the collection before returning it.

Comment: I have checked this: the only one who can possibly modify this list is the Constructor of the class holding it as a member. All others, including subclasses can access the list only by using this unmodifiable list:

Comment: In that case, see my answer on how to prevent modification and possibly detect where it is being modified.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to modify the list *inside* the iteration, like this:

```
Iterator iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  if (someCondition)
    list.remove(someObject);
}
```

Instead, this is what you should do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 if (someCondition)
    list.remove(i--);
 }
```

If your logic allows, you could use the CopyOnWriteArrayList. This implementation gives you a fresh copy of the list everytime you modify it. This is useful for situations where you do a lot of iterations, but few modifications, to a list, and where a given iteration don't need to reflect recent modifications to the list. I have used it a lot in dispatcher/subscriber applications, and it works great performancewise.

Comment: EDIT: If list really is unmodifiable, my response above does not apply obviously....sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a Collection and then use an existing iterator on it -- are you trying to modify the list somewhere (and here I mean the *original* list as well)?

From [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread.

Comment: if it is unmodifiable, how could I modify it then; either this is JVM problem, or my understanding of unmodifiable is completely wrong...

Comment: "Unmodifiable" here means that you will get a runtime exception if you try to modify it.

But we are really all just shooting in the dark, because you're not giving us the stacktrace.